# Dynamic textview not selectable and clickable in Android tv with remote control

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tv

i have created dynamic textview inside listview's row, but that textview is not focusable by TV remote control, i wanted to know is there any specific property for textview, that i need to set?

Source code here:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final EventData item = list.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_livesports, null);

        holder.nameTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
        holder.teamsTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.teamsTV);
        holder.startsTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.startTV);
        holder.channelLL = (TableLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.channelLL);
        holder.catIV = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.catIV);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.nameTV.setText(item.getName() + " : " + item.getTeams());
    holder.teamsTV.setText(item.getTeams());
    holder.startsTV.setText(item.getStarts());


    setDrawals(holder.catIV, item);

    TableRow tr_head = null;
    holder.channelLL.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < item.linkList.size(); i++) {
        TextView v = new TextView(ctx);

        final Spanned name = Html.fromHtml("<font color='#0000FF'>"
                + item.linkList.get(i).channelName + "</font>");
        final String link = item.linkList.get(i).channelLink;
        v.setText(name);

        if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10) {
            tr_head = new TableRow(ctx);
            tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        v.setPadding(20, 15, 20, 15);
        tr_head.addView(v);


        v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Toast.makeText(ctx, name, 1).show();
                linkListener.onLinkClicked(link);

            }
        });
        if (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10)
            holder.channelLL.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: please, Show your code?

Comment: Please have a look, i edited question with source code

Answer (score 1):

Is this in a `RecyclerView`?

With a DPAD, there is not a way to focus on a TextView unless you manually override and write an `onKeyDown` method that performs a click when the enter key is tapped.

You may want to write an `onClickListener` for the whole view and then when an enter key is detected, get the current view and perform a click.

RecyclerView:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do stuff
        }
    });
```

And in your activity:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  switch(keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(index).itemView.performClick();
            break;
  }   
}
```

Comment: hi Nick thanks for your answer..i'm not using Recyclerview..but i got your point..will vote your answer if successfull